# Error when using two different user agents

Tags: sip

I have 2 sip clients on the same computer.

Both of them is registering to a server that is running on port 5060.

For the first client the UDP is on port 5060 and for the other is 5061. When I come from one client to another, after the ringing part i receive the error:

> only one usage of each socket address is normally permited.

Got any ideas why I got this error?

Comment: C++ (as in the title) or C# (in your tag)?  And more detail (actual error messages, code) would be very helpful.

Comment: Are you using TCP or UDP for your connection to the server?

Answer (score 1):

Your server **and** client are both trying to use port 5060, hence the error message. Change the first client to use 5062 or something else.

Also, 5061 is normally used for secured SIP (normal listening port + 1 in the proxy/server). Do not use it for the second client.

Answer (score 0):

It means you're clients are both trying to claim the same socket for the communication channel, or the server is trying to reclaim the socket given to client A, to reuse it for client B.

The software handeling the socket, should be smart enough to rely on the OS to assign port numbers instead of hardcoding the port numbers in the code, this is a 100% guarantee for socket issues.